# Filter data get from doc

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting data from firestore like this

```
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(LIKE_COLLECTION).doc(globalProviderState.getID).get().then((value){
      print(value);
    });
```

I want to get value which is in data but its showing `Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'`;

This is how it looks like in firestore i just want to print all oppositeId which is in doc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` in your print statement is of type `DocumentSnapshot`. You have to call `.data()` to get the actual value (Map<String, dynamic>).

See below

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(LIKE_COLLECTION)
    .doc(globalProviderState.getID)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  print(value.data()); // <-- .data() called here
});
```